# What is the command to get the available shells in Hp-Unix along with the version number?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to unix. I am looking for the command which can show me shell's version. I am able to find the available shells by using the command `ls /bin/*sh*` but i am not able to find the command which can show me versions...

Please help. Also let me know if the same command can be run on AIX/Solaris Unix.

Comment: command is :- ls /bin/{asterisk}sh{asterisk}

Answer (score 1):

There might be some enviornment variable for showing the version: for bash I used following to get version:

`[mandy@mandy mpix]$ echo $BASH_VERSION`

`3.2.25(1)-release`

or Simply run `shell_name --version` command.

Comment: shell_name --version is working only for bash shell. it is not showing versions for other shells, even if shells are installed and there...

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to query a Unix executable for its version; each command has it's own approach. Some use the `--version` option, others use `-v`. With shells, some of them have no way to query the version without starting the shell. When you're inside the shell, you can try to find the version with the command

```
set | grep -i version
```

**[EDIT]** As a last resort, you can check the system manuals of your OS. Many Unix systems use some kind of package management software. Find out which package installed the executable. The package manager should then be able to tell you the version of the package.

Comment: Even i tried that but not getting the expected results in. Whenever i am trying the same it is showing me nothing..simple blank line. I have tried that in Hp-UX, AIX, Solaris..

Comment: isn't there any command/shell script for this? Normally with linux it is like <shell _name> --version, which works for all shells...??

Comment: No. Unix != Linux != HP-UX != AIX != Solaris. Linux, at least, has been written to solve technical problems but HP-UX, AIX and Solaris have partly been written by marketing departments and "clever" engineers. You will have to write such a script/command for each of those systems and sometimes for each version of them, too.

Answer (score -2):

These interpretors will definitely cry out aloud when you do something wrong.

So do that,

> abc

zsh: command not found: abc

Comment: -1 Sorry, but your answer is unrelated to the question